# Send string on serial monitor Arduino tinkercad

Tags: arduino-uno

I have problem with my code. I wanna send alphanumeric on serial monitor Arduino. I hope someone can help

```
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
if ( Serial.available())
{
char datachar = Serial.read();
}
delay(1000)

serial.print(datachar)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not compile because of the following errors:

- The statements `delay(1000)` and `serial.print(datachar)` are missing the `;` at the end.
- The variable `datachar` is declared inside the `if` block, so it will not be available outside when you call `serial.print(datachar)`.
- You misspelled the word `serial` in `serial.print(datachar)`, it should start with an uppercase letter.

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  char datachar;
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    datachar = Serial.read();
  }
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print(datachar);
}
```